# How to get first 2 rows have same month and year bases on a date field with unixtimestamp

Tags: mysql, database

I've a places table which has a datetime field named `visited_date` with unixtimestamp.

If there's more than two rows in the table which have same month and year, I need to get only the first 2 rows. [This is my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFlCj.png)

For instances, if my table is like this:

```
id|visited_date(month from unix stamp)|year(From unix timestamp )
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1 |2                                  |2016                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2 |2                                  |2016                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3 |2                                  |2016                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
4 |8                                  |2017                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the expected result:

```
id|visited_date(month from unix stamp)|year(From unix timestamp )
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1 |2                                  |2016                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2 |2                                  |2016                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
4 |8                                  |2017                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you need the first two rows, or the first two per month?

Comment: First two per month, ( where month and year are same )

Comment: You have a pic of your table?

Comment: Also, what you have inside of () is confusing. Can you explain better?

Comment: @tiagoperes , Please find my update ..

Comment: what do you mean get the first two rows? sort them with which order?

Comment: the result is confusing me, it has there the id 4 for which reason?

Comment: In the result the id 3 is denied because the first two rows with id 1 and 2 have same month and year and the id 4 is next so its taken ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM places
WHERE year IN (
    SELECT year
    FROM places
    GROUP BY year
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
```

The idea is to use the inner query to identify the records which have `year` value that occurs 1 or 2 times in the data.

Then, get all columns from the table based on that set of values.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution :

```
SELECT
 id,
    year_,
    month_
FROM(
 SELECT
  tp.id,
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as year_, 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as month_,
  @rn := IF(@prev = CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date))), @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
  @prev := CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)))
 FROM tr_place tp
 JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars WHERE tp.location_id = 211
 ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC,MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC
) AS T1
WHERE rn < 3;
```

This Query gives what I need ...